# Difference between "uniformly continuous on $\Omega$" and "uniformly continuous on all bounded subsets of $\Omega$"

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Define
$$
X:=\{f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}\mid f\textrm{ is bounded and uniformly continuous on $\Omega$}\}.
$$
and
$$
Y:=\{f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}\mid f\textrm{ is uniformly continuous on all bounded subsets of $\Omega$}\}.
$$

When $\Omega$ is bounded, one can see that $X=Y$. When $\Omega$ is unbounded, it is clear that $X\subset Y$. Here is my **question**:

> When $\Omega$ is unbounded, is $Y\subset X$ also true?

---

[Added:] Thanks to the quick response, one can see that $Y\subset X$ is not necessarily true. What really puzzles me is the difference between "uniformly continuous on $\Omega$" and "uniformly continuous on all bounded subsets of $\Omega$". Let
$$Y':=\{f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}\mid f\textrm{ is bounded on $\Omega$ and uniformly continuous on all bounded subsets of $\Omega$}\}.$$
Do we still have an example for $Y'\setminus X$?

Comment: Example: $n=1$, $\Omega=\Bbb R$. The function $f(x):=x^2$ is an element of $Y$ but not of $X$.

Comment: The example still holds for $Y'$, since $f(x)=x^2$ is indeed bounded on every bounded subset. (Or is your wording just ambiguous here?) Did you mean functions which are _uniformly bounded_?

Comment: @Roland, thanks for pointing that out. I edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n=1$, $\Omega=\mathbb R$. The function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=x$ is clearly unbounded, so $f\notin X$. However, $f$ is uniformly continuous on bounded subsets of $\mathbb R$; in fact, it is uniformly continuous on all of $\mathbb R$ because
$$
|x-y|<\epsilon\implies |f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y|<\epsilon.
$$
Thus $f\in Y\setminus X$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a function in $Y' \setminus X$.

Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$. Then $x \mapsto \sin(x^2)$ is bounded, uniformly continuous on any bounded subset of $\Omega$, and not uniformly continuous on $\Omega$. In fact, if $f$ is continuous and unbounded then $\sin \circ f \in Y' \setminus X$.